# vim indentation: disable inference of enumerated list

Tags: vim, indentation

In vim, when I format the following paragraph in a plain text file using `gqip`, the formatter indents it like an enumerated list.

Original paragraph:

```
Here is some text including a number
3 in the paragraph, which may be
regarded as the start of a numbered
list when I format it.
```

Formatted (after `gqip`):

```
Here is some text including a number
3 in the paragraph, which may be
  regarded as the start of a numbered
list when I format it.
```

The problem is that vim aligns the word "regarded" as if the line "3 in the paragraph..." somehow means "(3) in the paragraph". In my opinion, this is a bug in the formatting rules, because there are obvious counter-examples that occur frequently in ordinary text. So how can I refine this indentation rule to apply only when there is list-like punctuation on the number? For example, I think this is ok:

```
Here is some text including a number
3) in the paragraph, which may be
   regarded as the start of a numbered
list when I format it.
```

There are counter-examples to this rule as well, but at least the error occurs less frequently. The rule could be further refined by checking for balanced parentheses--i.e.:

```
Here is some text (including a number
3) in the paragraph, which is not
regarded as the start of a numbered
list when I format it (because the 
parenthesis is accounted for by the
opening parenthesis on line 1).
```

Comment: What's the plain text file's filetype?

Comment: The file type is plain text. Do you mean to ask what is the extension? The filename is "foo.txt", though the same indentation occurs for latex files having extension ".tex".

Comment: What is the output of `:set fo?`?

Comment: `:set fo` shows `formatoptions=ncroql`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See `:h fo-table` 's `n` letter meaning, then see `:h formatlistpat`, which is used to recogize a list header:

```
" 'formatlistpat' 'flp' string (default: "^\s*\d\+[\]:.)}\t ]\s*")

" ignore '3 ' by removing space in pattern
let &formatlistpat='^\s*\d\+[\]:.)}\t]\s*'

" ignore (\n3) or [\n3] or {\n3} by adding a preceding NOT match
let &formatlistpat='\([\[({]\s*\n\)\@<!\_^\s*\d\+[\]:.)}\t]\s*'
```